# Zend Wurfl Mobile Server Error

Tags: php, zend-framework, user-agent, wurfl

Hi i try to add mobile template into current zend application but it return server error.
Following are my configuration as i follow on several sites.

application.in

```
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Rate_Application_Mobile"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_api_version = "1.1"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_lib_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/wurfl/WURFL/"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_file = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/wurfl-config.php"
```

wurfl-config.php

```
<?php
$resourcesDir            = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../data/wurfl/';

$wurfl['main-file']      = $resourcesDir  . 'wurfl-2.0.27.zip';
$wurfl['patches']        = array($resourcesDir . 'web_browsers_patch.xml');

$persistence['provider'] = 'file';
$persistence['dir']      = $resourcesDir . 'cache/';

$cache['provider']       = null;

$configuration['wurfl']       = $wurfl;
$configuration['persistence'] = $persistence;
$configuration['cache']       = $cache;
```

Mobile Plugin
/var/www/library/Rate/Application/Mobile.php

```
class Rate_Application_Mobile extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $req)
    {


        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $bootstrap = $front->getParam("bootstrap");

        $userAgent = $bootstrap->getResource('useragent');

        $device = $userAgent->getDevice();  --> this part return server error when switching to mobile browser, otherwise it return desktop when view as desktop browser


    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Update: Error return as follow

```
Warning: include(/var/www/library/wurfl/WURFL/Storage/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/library/wurfl/WURFL/ClassLoader.php on line 42

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/library/wurfl/WURFL/Storage/.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/application/../library:/var/www/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/local/Zend/library') in /var/www/library/wurfl/WURFL/ClassLoader.php on line 42

Fatal error: Class 'WURFL_Storage_' not found in /var/www/library/wurfl/WURFL/Storage/Factory.php on line 43
```

Comment: What's exactly the error?

Comment: it return server error

Comment: Yep, I did understand that, but does it return literal `server error` string or something more? No messages, codes, anything? Maybe some `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` at the top of the script will help?

Comment: hi the above is the error it returns, i had no idea what it means since all files are in right place..

Comment: This is PHP error stating that class file was not found. You're including empty name PHP file, so WURFL probably can't detect what it needs to load. Please do a `debug_backtrace()` before error line in `ClassLoader.php:42` (first error) and check what storage it tries / needs to load in `Factory.php:43`. If it's this file: https://github.com/knnktr-labs/wurfl/blob/master/WURFL/Storage/Factory.php you're trying to load a `file` provider which should be specified in `provider` config tree which you do provide, but it's not read.

Comment: For now please clear ZF cache, and check if `$persistence['provider'] = 'file';`, `$cache['provider']       = null;` and `$configuration['persistence'] = $persistence;` do not interfere.

Comment: Great it works, now how can redirect from default module to mobile module? I have a module for mobile

Comment: Simply check what WURFL is expected to return on mobile and desktop, and act accordingly (switch templates or something). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630180/how-to-detect-desktop-browser-vs-mobile-device-using-wurfl . Also, please upvote and accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is an answer I gave in the comments above, copied and pasted just for the sake of upvoting and accepting.**

This is PHP error stating that class file was not found. You're including empty name PHP file, so WURFL probably can't detect what it needs to load. Please do a debug_backtrace() before error line in ClassLoader.php:42 (first error) and check what storage it tries / needs to load in Factory.php:43. If it's this file: [Factory.php](https://github.com/knnktr-labs/wurfl/blob/master/WURFL/Storage/Factory.php) you're trying to load a file provider which should be specified in provider config tree which you do provide, but it's not read.

For now please clear ZF cache, and check if

```
$persistence['provider'] = 'file';
$cache['provider'] = null;
$configuration['persistence'] = $persistence;
```

do not interfere.